# vista de una api

Tags: python, django

Estoy consumiendo una api la cual tiene hasta ahora artículos, categorías y usuarios. Cuando hago una consulta de la api en la url para usuarios me aparece la información tanto en lista como información individual de la api /users/1 (ejemplo). cuando hago lo mismo con categorías esta solo me muestra en nombre y id de la categoría individual consultada /categories/1 sin embargo no me muestra la listas de categorías que poseo como lo hace con users o articles. Revise las rutas que poseo y debería de estar adjunto:

```
admin/
api/ ^users/$ [name='users-list']
api/ ^users/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$ [name='users-detail']
api/ ^$ [name='articles-list']
api/ ^(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$ [name='articles-detail']
api/ ^categories/$ [name='categories-list']
api/ ^categories/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$ [name='categories-detail']
api-auth/
api/rest-auth/
api/rest-auth/registration/
schema/
docs/
```

adjunto mis archivo para la view:

```
class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
permission_classes = (IsAuthorOrReadOnly, IsAuthenticated)
queryset = Article.objects.all()
serializer_class = ArticleSerializer

class CategoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Category.objects.all()
serializer_class = CategorySerializer

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = get_user_model().objects.all()
serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

mis archivo para serializer y urls:

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta: 
    fields = ('id', 'author', 'title', 'description', 'content', 'category', 'url', 'photo', 'created_at', 'updated_at')
    model = Article



class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta: 
    fields = ('id', 'category_name')
    model = Category


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    fields = ('id', 'username',)
    model = get_user_model()
```

las rutas:

```
router = SimpleRouter()
router.register('users', UserViewSet, base_name='users')
router.register('', ArticleViewSet, base_name='articles')
router.register('categories', CategoryViewSet, base_name='categories')

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Comment: Confirmame lo siguiente a ver si entiendo tu problema. Ocurre que al acceder a /users/ hace una lista de usuarios, pero al hacer /categories/ no lista todas las categorias. Siendo que al hacer recuperación mediante /categories/<id> si funciona con una sola instancia?  Cual es el stacktrace completo del error que ocurre al intentar acceder a lo que deseas?

Comment: @Vichoko hola si correcto solo que para la lista de categorías no me da ninguna me da un 404 de hecho

Comment: Si es así entonces te afirmo que el codigo que presentas enlaza correctamente la URL servidor/api/categories/ tal y como dice la traza del error 404 que colocas en la pregunta. Por lo que es posible que la URL haya sido ingresada incorrecta,emte. Notar el / que debe haber al final de la URL.

Comment: @Vichoko si debería pero aun asi es raro solo me lleva a la instancia si le paso el parámetro del id al final de la ruta presentada.  aun asi la ruta de la lista de categorias me la muestra con 404 y el mensaje:

{
    "detail": "Not found."
}